# How to select frame rate when recording webcam

Tags: video, quicktime, webcam

In OS X 10.10.5, I'm using QuickTime X to record video from a Logitech c920 webcam.  The only video options I see are High (720p30 H.264) and Maximum (1080p24 ProRes 444).  How can I independently specify frame rate, resolution, and codec?  I know this camera supports a wide variety of frame rates and sizes, because it's shown in ffmpeg through AVfoundation.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using OS X 10.10.5

Comment: Can you update the question to say this?